# How to map one to many

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, addresses

I am working on rent agreement and I have a situation here

1. One landlord can have multiple properties
2. every property have different details (property details, values)

now I want to link property details to property id also want to link  id's to landlord address.

Comment: use nested mapping.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contain owner's information in one mapping, where one variable can be an array of property Ids and create another mapping for each property Id to its relevant information.

```
    struct owner{
        uint[] propertyIds;
        uint totalarea;
        address[] clients;
    }
    mapping (address => owner) owners;

    struct property{
        uint id;
        string location;
        string area;
        uint price;
    }
    mapping (uint=> property) properties;
```

Or if you don't want to store anything else for an owner, you can directly map an address to an array.

```
struct property{
    uint id;
    string location;
    string area;
    uint price;
}
mapping (address => property[]) owners;
```